# Mapping Dictionaries in different list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, web-scraping

So here I have the following list and dictionaries:

```
{'linked': {'instructors.v1': 
                 [{'id': '3219339', 'fullName': 'Lisa Mazzola'}, 
                  {'id': '6407572',  'fullName': 'Alan S. Miller '}, 
                  {'id': '226710',   'fullName': 'Kevin Werbach'}, 
                  {'id': '8054217',  'fullName': '许 肖潇'}, 
                  {'id': '20696355', 'fullName': 'Варшалович Дмитрий Александрович'},  
                  {'id': '15622422', 'fullName': 'Prof. James Evans'}}], 

'elements': 
    [{ 'id': '69Bku0KoEeWZtA4u62x6lQ', 'name': 'Gamification','instructorIds': '226710'}]

 }
```

I am trying to obtain the 'fullName' from 'instructors.v1' associated with the 'instructorIds' from the 'elements' by matching both.
My approach--> created another dictionary as follows:

```
{'3219339': 'Lisa Mazzola'}
{'6407572': 'Alan S. Miller'}
{'226710': 'Kevin Werbach'}
```

This gives me a KeyError: "'226710'" even though 226710 does exist in the list.Please suggest another approach, else, where am I going wrong?

here is the python code for your reference:

```
import imp
import importlib
import requests
import json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import sys
import urllib.request
from importlib import reload

if __name__ == "__main__":
headers = ({
    "x-user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36 
FKUA/website/41/website/Desktop"})

url = "https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?start=0&limit=20&includes=instructorIds,partnerIds,specializations,s12nlds,v1Details,v2Details&fields=instructorIds,partnerIds,specializations,s12nlds,description"
data = requests.get(url).json()
# print(len(data['elements']))
print(data)

with open("courserarough1.csv", 'a') as f:
                                        ##### Header #####

    header = f.write(
        'instructors' + ',' + 'courseURL' + ',' + 'courseType' + ',' + 
    'CourseName' + ',' + 'partnerName' + ',' +
        'slug' + ',' + 'specializations' + ',' + 'course_id' + ',' + 
    'description' + ',' + "\n")


    for n in range( len( data['linked']['instructors.v1'] ) ):
        instructors = data['linked']['instructors.v1'][n]['fullName']
        instructors = str( instructors )
        instructors = instructors.strip().replace( ',', '' )

        instructorsid = data['linked']['instructors.v1'][n]['id']
        instructorsid = str( instructorsid )
        instructorsid = instructorsid.strip().replace( ',', '' )
        newdict = dict( [(instructorsid,instructors)] )
        print(newdict)
    #print(data['linked']['instructors.v1'])

    partnerlist = []
    for m in range( len( data['linked']['partners.v1'] ) ):
         partnerName = data['linked']['partners.v1'][m]['name']
         partnerName = str( partnerName )
         partnerid = data['linked']['partners.v1'][m]['id']
         partnerid = str( partnerid )

         partnerlist.append(partnerid)

    #print(partnerlist)


    for i in range(len(data['elements'])):

        partnerIds = data['elements'][i]['partnerIds']
        #filtered = data[(np.where( partnerlist.__contains__(partnerIds) ))]
        #print(filtered)
        courseType = data['elements'][i]['courseType']
        courseType = str(courseType)
        if courseType:
            courseType = courseType.rstrip().replace('v2.', '')
        else:
            courseType = ' '
        # print(courseType)
        CourseName = data['elements'][i]['name']
        CourseName = str(CourseName)

        CourseName = CourseName.strip().replace(',', '')

        partnerIds = data['elements'][i]['partnerIds']
        partnerIds = str( partnerIds )
        if partnerIds:
            partnerIds = partnerIds.rstrip().replace( ',', '' )
            partnerIds = partnerIds.rstrip().replace( '\n', '' )
            partnerIds = partnerIds.rstrip().replace( 'u', '' )
            partnerIds = partnerIds.rstrip().replace( '[', '' )
            partnerIds = partnerIds.rstrip().replace( ']', '' )
        else:
            partnerIds = ' '

        slug = data['elements'][i]['slug']
        slug = str(slug)
        # print(slug)
        specializations = data['elements'][i]['specializations']
        specializations = str(specializations)
        if specializations:
            specializations = specializations.rstrip().replace(',', '')
            specializations = specializations.rstrip().replace('\n', '')
            specializations = specializations.rstrip().replace('u', '')
            specializations = specializations.rstrip().replace('[', '')
            specializations = specializations.rstrip().replace(']', '')
        else:
            specializations = ' '

        course_id = data['elements'][i]['id']
        course_id = str(course_id)

        description = data['elements'][i]['description']
        description = str(description)

        if description:
            description = description.strip().replace(',', '')
            description = description.strip().replace('\n', '')

        else:
            description = ' '

        courseURL = "https://www.coursera.org/learn/" + slug
        courseURL = str(courseURL)

        instructorIds = data['elements'][i]['instructorIds']

        instructorIds = str( instructorIds )
        if instructorIds:
            instructorIds = instructorIds.rstrip().replace( ',', '' )
            instructorIds = instructorIds.rstrip().replace( '\n', '' )
            instructorIds = instructorIds.rstrip().replace( 'u', '' )
            instructorIds = instructorIds.rstrip().replace( '[', '' )
            instructorIds = instructorIds.rstrip().replace( ']', '' )

            instructorIds = re.sub( r'^"|"$', '', instructorIds )
        else:
            instructorIds = ' '
        #print(instructorIds)

        instructors = newdict[instructorIds]
        print(instructors)






                                                                ##writing the 
        attributes in a csv file##
        f.write(instructors + ',' + courseURL + ',' + courseType + ',' + 
        CourseName + ',' + partnerName + ',' + slug +
            ',' + specializations + ',' + course_id + ',' + description + 
         "\n")
```

Comment: Please show us what u have tried

Comment: It would be more helpful if you also added a code snipped you used to extract the data. Also note that "instructor.v1" is an array of dictionaries and in the '226710' is a value not the key, the key is 'id'.

Comment: @AnisH_GuptA  yes exactly..so that is the reason I created another dictionary called 'newdict' where I can use '226710' as the key so that I get the name as the value.

Comment: you only need the value `{'3219339': 'Lisa Mazzola'}` or you want to assign it to associated id which is in element i.e. `{'id' : 'tEqImn2kEeWb-BLhFdaGww', instructur(s):[{'3219339': 'Lisa Mazzola'}]}`

Comment: I just need the corresponding value to the key -->                                          print(instructorIds)  gives  '226710'                                                                          and then -->  instructors = newdict[instructorIds]    gives  KeyError: "'226710'"

Comment: then your reference code is bit large. I'll make you one simpler one where in same API you will get `[{'3219339': 'Lisa Mazzola'}]` instead of `['3219339']`. will it work for you?

Comment: At the same time, if I run the code for just 1 item, It correctly matches and returns the name based on instructorIds.

Comment: @Gahan Sure lets give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url = "https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?start=0&limit=20&includes=instructorIds,partnerIds,specializations,s12nlds,v1Details,v2Details&fields=instructorIds,partnerIds,specializations,s12nlds,description"
url = "https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?start=0&limit=20&includes=instructorIds&fields=instructorIds" # for brief I have shorten api call
data = requests.get(url).text
json_data = json.loads(data)
cmp1 = json_data['elements']
cmp2 = json_data['linked']['instructors.v1']
for element in cmp1:
    new_list = []
    for ids in element['instructorIds']:
        for inst in cmp2:
            new_dict = {}
            if ids in inst['id']:
                new_dict[ids] = inst['fullName']
                new_list.append(new_dict)
    element['instructorIds'] = new_list

print(cmp1)
json_data['elements'] = cmp1
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp: # file data.json will generated in the directory from which you execute this script. assign full path to store json file to your desire place.
    json.dump(json_data, fp, sort_keys=False, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

**Some of the sample JSON output:**

```
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "Gamification",
            "slug": "gamification",
            "instructorIds": [
                {
                    "226710": "Kevin Werbach"
                }
            ],
            "courseType": "v2.ondemand",
            "id": "69Bku0KoEeWZtA4u62x6lQ"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dealing With Missing Data",
            "slug": "missing-data",
            "instructorIds": [
                {
                    "8394050": "Richard Valliant, Ph.D."
                }
            ],
            "courseType": "v2.ondemand",
            "id": "0HiU7Oe4EeWTAQ4yevf_oQ"
        },
...
...
...
...
...
        {
            "name": "Accounting Analytics",
            "slug": "accounting-analytics",
            "instructorIds": [
                {
                    "1937011": "Brian J Bushee"
                },
                {
                    "14757138": "Christopher D. Ittner"
                }
            ],
            "courseType": "v2.ondemand",
            "id": "rc5KG0aUEeWG1w6arGoEIQ"
        },
        {
            "name": "Municipal Solid Waste Management in Developing Countries",
            "slug": "solid-waste-management",
            "instructorIds": [
                {
                    "2387594": "Dr. Christian Zurbrügg"
                },
                {
                    "7293234": "Imanol Zabaleta"
                },
                {
                    "16974677": "Félix Schmidt"
                }
            ],
            "courseType": "v2.ondemand",
            "id": "gpAI9GK4EeWFkQ7sUCFGVQ"
        },
...
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. That helped!